# Excel: Omitting rows/columns from VBA macro

Tags: vba, excel

With some help, I've put together two functions that will work in unison to first convert all of my data from the "text" format to a "number" format.  After which it will set each column to a fixed number of characters.

The two sub-routines I'm using are listed below, but I can't figure out how to omit certain rows/columns for the respective functions.

When running the psAdd function, I want to omit the first 3 rows from the range, and for the FormatFixedNumber function I want to omit several columns.  The problem with the latter is that I have 1000+ columns of data and a key header row containing a 1 or 0 that represents whether the column should be converted.

How could modify this code to skip the first 3 rows in the first sub, and several columns marked with a 0 in the second?

```
Sub psAdd()  
    Dim x As Range 'Just a blank cell for variable
    Dim z As Range 'Selection to work with

    Set z = Cells
    Set x = Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Offset(1)
    If x <> "" Then
        Exit Sub
    Else
        x.Copy
        z.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll, Operation:=xlAdd
        Application.CutCopyMode = False 'Kill copy mode
    End If
    x.ClearContents 'Back to normal
End Sub

Sub FormatFixedNumber()

    Dim i As Long

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    For i = 1 To lastCol 'replace 10 by the index of the last column of your spreadsheet
        With Columns(i)
            .NumberFormat = String(.Cells(2, 1), "0") 'number length is in second row
        End With
    Next i
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**1. First code**

At the moment you are working on all the cells on a sheet with `z`. You can reduce this to the `UsedRange` - ignoring the first three rows by

- forcing the `UsedRange` to update before using it (to avoid redunant cells)
- testing if the `z` exceeds 3 rows
- if so resize `z` by three rows using `Offset` and `Resize`

  ```
  Sub psAdd()
  Dim x As Range    'Just a blank cell for variable
  Dim z As Range    'Selection to work with
  ActiveSheet.UsedRange
  Set z = ActiveSheet.UsedRange
  If z.Rows.Count > 3 Then
      Set z = z.Cells(1).Offset(3, 0).Resize(z.Rows.Count - 3, z.Columns.Count)
  End If
  'using Rows is better than hard-coding 65536 (bottom of xl03 - but not xl07-10)
  Set x = Cells(Rows.Count,"A").End(xlUp).Offset(1)
  If x <> "" Then
      Exit Sub
  Else
      x.Copy
      z.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll, Operation:=xlAdd
      Application.CutCopyMode = False    'Kill copy mode
  End If
  x.ClearContents    'Back to normal
  End Sub
  ```

**2. Second code**

Run a simple test on each header cell to proceed if it doesn't equal 0. Assuming that the header cell is in row 1 then

```
Sub FormatFixedNumber()
    Dim i As Long
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    For i = 1 To lastCol    'replace 10 by the index of the last column of your spreadsheet
        If Cells(1, i) <> 0 Then
            With Columns(i)
                .NumberFormat = String(.Cells(2, 1), "0")    'number length is in second row
            End With
        End If
    Next i
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: If I understand the question correctly regarding the second piece od code, the 0 is on row 2, so the condition would be `If Cells(2, i) <> 0 Then`.

Comment: I also want the second piece of code to omit the first few header rows like the first piece of code.